# Rails use searchkick for multi fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire, searchkick

I recently add `searchkick` on my web app, but the research works only on the name fields.
There's my code :

MODEL :

```
class Campaign
 [...]

   searchkick language: "French"

 [...]

  def self.search_fields(params)
    @query = "*#{params[:search]}*"
    @search = Campaign.search @query, fields: [:name, :categories, :professional, :brief] , misspellings: {distance: 2}
    @search.results
  end
```

But, at

```
@search = Campaign.search @query, fields: [:name, :categories, :professional, :brief] , misspellings: {distance: 2}
```

The research works only on the name of every model. But I want to search with other fields, like :categories, :professional, :brief, :date etc etc.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You should define which fields you want to index in model

```
class Campaign
  [...]
  def search_data
    {
      name: name,
      categories: categories,
      professional: professional,
      brief: brief
    }
  end
  [...]
end
```

remember to reindex this model after above changes.

ref: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#indexing